# How to scroll to the selected option on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the focus button I want the select box to automatically scroll and then show the selected option.I am unable to achieve it using focus. Is there any javascript or jQuery method which can help me fix this ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#focus").click(function () {
                    $("select#selectId").find(":selected").focus();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select title="Title" id="selectId" style="width: 143px; height: 125px; overflow: scroll;" multiple="multiple">
        <option  value="1">1 </option>
        <option  value="2">2 </option>
        <option  value="3">3</option>
        <option  value="4">4</option>
        <option  value="5">5</option>
        <option  value="6">6</option>
        <option  value="7">7</option>
        <option  value="8">8</option>
        <option  value="9">9</option>
        <option  value="10">10</option>
        <option  value="11">11</option>
        <option  value="12">12</option>
        <option  value="13">13</option>
        <option  value="14">14</option>
        <option  value="15">15</option>
        <option  value="16">16</option>
        <option  value="17">17</option>
        <option  value="18">18</option>
        <option  value="19">19</option>
        <option  value="20">20</option>
        <option  value="21">21</option>
        <option  value="22">22</option>
        <option  value="23">23</option>
        <option  value="24">24</option>
        <option  value="25">25</option>
        <option  value="26">26</option>
        <option  value="27">27</option>
        <option  value="28">28</option>
        <option  value="31">31</option></select>
        <button type="button" id="focus">focus on selected</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try `$("select#selectId").find(":selected").scrollTo();`

Comment: What if 1 and 31 are the selected options?

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollTo'

Comment: Yeah, `scrollTo` isn't a jQuery method but a vanilla approach.

Comment: you have to choose one or use a different solution like hiding options that aren't selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple script . This is a better answer because in my case, the contents of the select change dynamically so the scroll height is not a constant. Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/962vxk4f/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#focus").click(function (e) {
      $selectId = $("#selectId");
      var $index = $selectId.find(":selected").index();
      var lastPos = 0;
      $selectId.children().each(function () { lastPos++; });
      var currScrollPos = ($index / lastPos) * parseInt($selectId[0].scrollHeight);
      $selectId.scrollTop(currScrollPos);
   });
});
```

Comment: Great solution, but what if the select element's options are not displayed at the time of click? I'm sure your answer is 99% of the solution, but I can't find that last little piece.

For example, if you remove the "style" and "multiple" properties, and move the code to an onClick of the select instead of onClick of the button.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `scrollIntoView()` DOM method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#focus").click(function () {
        $("#selectId").focus().find(":selected")[0].scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** doesn't work on IE11 (other vs???)

Comment: It didnt work. Can you please provide another solution ?

Comment: It works for me, can you provide a sample where it is not working? What if more than one option selected? What is your expected behaviour? Etc...

Comment: Hi. Only one option is selected. When i click the button then nothing happens. I want the select box to scroll and show me the selected option.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/1oxb2f0j/  If doesn't work for you, then you are doing something wrong obviously.

Comment: @Karthik that's correct, just tested it on IE11 and it doesn't scroll. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#focus").click(function () {
     var indx = $("select#selectId").find(":selected").index();
     $('#selectId').animate({
        scrollTop: indx * 14
     }, 500);
 });
});
```

You can also use this, you can able to control scroll speed here.

Comment: @Karthik You have to do some effort because obviously in answer's posted code, `indx` is defined, so what?!

Comment: Ohh Sorry. indx is defined and this worked for me. Thanks vinoth kumar and Wolf

Comment: Can you please explain why you multiplied index with 14 ?

Comment: Scroll scrolls to a pixel. I assume his select shows 14 items at a time. 
So, for instance if the selected index is 10, you need to multiple 10x14 to scroll to pixel #140.